# Execution failed for task ':google_maps_flutter:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, google-maps-flutter

Was in the process of integration and this error kept occuring tried multiple answers such as using `flutter clean` or changing the CompiledSdk to no avail. i am debugging on Pixel 2 XL Api level 27.

Here is the output of `flutter run -v` : https://pastebin.com/UdaFSFvP

Here is the `pubspec.yaml` : https://pastebin.com/UdaFSFvP

Here is the output of `flutter doctor` : https://pastebin.com/4DThja3W

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.8, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.778], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
[√] Android Studio (version 3.5)
[!] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2019.1)
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available
! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i solved this.

If you encounter this error try the following.

1.`flutter clean`

2.`delete pubspec.lock`

3.`flutter pub get`

4.check dependencies versions as some might be incompatible with your target Sdk (this was my error)